# Can't build app on macOS Intel but I can with new xcode install on Apple chip

Tags: xcode, react-native, bundle-identifier

On my intel machine, I get errors trying to build an app without first opening the project in xcode and then manually setting a bundle identifier. Only after that's done can I build the app with `npx react-native run-ios`

But I just set up a development environment on my m1 and I was able to build and launch the app in the simulator with no problem at all without ever having to touch xcode.

I'm wondering why the two machines might behave differently.